# Need to calculate overtime and regular hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have 1 table as `attendance`

```
|AttendanceresultId |   AccountID   |   Intime                  |     Outtime           |   ShiftID |       
|  1                |   1234        |   2016-06-21 06:56:00     |   NULL                |   1       |   
|  2                |   1234        |   NULL                    |   2016-06-21 17:02:00 |   1       |   
|  3                |   1234        |   2016-06-22 06:56:00     |   NULL                |   1       |   
|  4                |   1234        |   NULL                    |   2016-06-22 17:02:00 |   1       |   
|  5                |   1235        |   2016-06-21 22:55:00     |   NULL                |   3       |   
|  6                |   1235        |   NULL                    |   2016-06-22 06:00:00 |   3       |   
|  7                |   1235        |   2016-06-22 22:55:00     |   NULL                |   3       |   
|  8                |   1235        |   NULL                    |   2016-06-23 07:00:00 |   3       |
```

Another table is `shift` table

```
|   ShiftId     |   Starttime   |   Endtime     |
|   1           |   07:00:00.00 |   16:00:00.00 |
|   3           |   23:00:00.00 |   06:00:00.00 |
```

I want to calculate the total number of working hours and over time hours for an employee lets say,

Expected Output,

```
|   AccountID   |   NormalHours |   OvertimeHours   |    
|   1234        |   18:08   Hrs |   02:04 Hrs       |   
|   1235        |   14:10   Hrs |   01:00 Hrs       |
```

I am newbie in sql server can any one suggest anything

Comment: Isn't there a ShiftID per AccountID?

Comment: It may happen that employee is doing morning shift for 1 week and night shift for other

Answer (score 0):

I broke this into four Parts to adjust for the lack of the lag function in 2008:

1) Common Table Expression to organize the records (so as not to count on the identity field)

2) Calculates the total minutes worked and worked for overtime without using the lag function

3) I then summarize those minutes - and split them into hours and minutes.

4) I then format them.

That said, there are quite a few possible places where I think real world data might create issues.

Updated version that does not use the lag function

```
WITH TimeRecords (AccountID, InOutTime, Intime, OutTime, Shift,
 RowNumber) AS
(SELECT att.AccountID, COALESCE(att.Intime,att.OutTime), 
 att.Intime, att.OutTime, att.Shift,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY att.AccountID, 
                       COALESCE(att.InTime, att.OutTime) )
 FROM dbo.attendance att)
 ,  
ShiftTime AS (
        SELECT   trecout.AccountID ,
                    trecin.InTime,
                    trecout.OutTime,
                  --  sh.EndTime ,
  -- Number of Minutes for the entire shift
                    CASE WHEN trecout.OutTime IS NOT NULL
                         THEN DATEDIFF(mi,
                                       trecin.InTime,
                                       trecout.OutTime)
                         ELSE 0
                    END AS TotalTime ,
  -- Number of Minutes for overtime
                    CASE WHEN trecout.OutTime IS NOT NULL
                         THEN DATEDIFF(mi, sh.EndTime,
                                       CAST(trecout.OutTime AS TIME))
                         ELSE 0
                    END AS OverTime
           FROM     TimeRecords trecout
           JOIN     TimeRecords trecin
               ON trecout.RowNumber -1 = trecin.RowNumber

              JOIN dbo.ShiftID sh
                  ON trecout.[Shift] = sh.ShiftID
         )
         ,
  -- Summarize the data
    ShiftTimeSum
      AS ( SELECT   st.AccountID ,
                    FLOOR(SUM(st.TotalTime - st.OverTime) / 60) AS      RegularHours ,
                    SUM(st.TotalTime - st.OverTime) % 60 AS RegularMinutes ,
                    SUM(st.OverTime) / 60 AS OverTimeHours ,
                    SUM(st.OverTime) % 60 AS OverTimeMinutes
           FROM     ShiftTime st
           GROUP BY st.AccountID
         )
 -- Now format
  SELECT  sts.AccountID ,
    CAST(sts.RegularHours AS VARCHAR(5)) + ':'
    + RIGHT(CAST(( 100 + sts.RegularMinutes ) AS CHAR(3)), 2) AS RegularTime ,
    CAST(sts.OverTimeHours AS VARCHAR(5)) + ':'
    + RIGHT(CAST(( 100 + sts.OverTimeMinutes ) AS CHAR(3)), 2) AS OverTime
  FROM    ShiftTimeSum sts;
```

Comment: Adam Lag is not supported in sqlserver2008

Comment: I tested on 2012 and it works fine, but when i run the same query on 2008 it is not supporting

Comment: Code Above is now fixed

Comment: Adam, your code is working now. But regular time is showing more, I think it is showing regulartime + overtime in regulartime column and separately it is showing overtime also which is correct. Overtime is correct but regular time is not correct.

Comment: I ran the query and it produces the exact results of your post.  make sure you are running all the code. You'll see in the ShiftTimeSum period where overtime is explicitly subtracted from total time to get regular time

Comment: AccountID Intime    Outtime   ShiftID  
73803  NULL    2016-06-20 17:10:00 1 
73803  2016-06-21 06:56:00  2016-06-21 17:02:00 1 
73803  2016-06-22 06:53:00  2016-06-22 17:02:00 1 
73803  2016-06-23 06:53:00  2016-06-23 17:04:00 1 
73803  NULL    2016-06-23 17:04:00 1 
73803  2016-06-24 06:54:00  2016-06-24 17:09:00 1 
73803  2016-06-25 06:53:00  NULL   1 
73803  NULL    2016-06-25 16:03:00 1 
73803  2016-06-27 06:53:00  2016-06-27 17:03:00 1 
73803  2016-06-28 06:51:00  NULL   1 
73803  NULL    2016-06-28 17:01:00 1

Comment: Can we add excel sheet in comment I can show you what is missing